# Overlay icons in Windows with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why there's any node package that handle folders icons and overlay icons, either for Windows or others SOs?

I did some research, and appearently for windows you have to write a dll and register it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123(v=vs.85).aspx

But this isn't possible with Node? Because I want to create a folder with different icons and I can't find some easy way to do this with javascript.

Comment: who do think this should be on the server side and not on the client ?

Comment: windows-shortcuts
try this module may help you
[see this link related to your question ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-shortcuts)